# fill and scale_color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to color bars in ggplot but having issues. Can someone explain how to correctly use the `fill` parameter and the `scale_colour` parameters?

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(c(80,33,30),c("Too militarized","Just doing their job","Unfairly tarnished by a few"),c("57%","23%","21%"))
colnames(df)<-c("values","names","percentages")

ggplot(df,aes(names,values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge",fill=names)+
  geom_text(aes(label=percentages), vjust=0)+
  ylab("percentage")+
  xlab("thought")+
  scale_colour_manual(values = rainbow(nrow(df)))
```

Working barplot example

```
barplot(c(df$values),names=c("Too militarized","Just doing their job","Unfairly tarnished by a few"),col = rainbow(nrow(df)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you don't have `fill` inside a call to `aes` in `geom_bar()`.  When mapping from data to visuals like colors, it has to be inside `aes()`.  You can fix this by either wrapping `fill=names` with `aes()` or by just specifying fill colors directly, instead of using `names`:

Option 1 (no legend):

```
ggplot(df, aes(names, values)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=rainbow(nrow(df))) + 
  ylab("percentage") + 
  xlab("thought")
```

Option 2 (legend, because mapping from data to colors):

```
ggplot(df, aes(names, values)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=names)) + 
  ylab("percentage") + 
  xlab("thought") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=rainbow(nrow(df)))
```

Note that in both cases you might want to explicitly factor `df$names` ahead of the call to `ggplot` in order to get the bars in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks for providing both solutions- that really helped!